# Why does firefox show a shadow beneath my CSS shape?

Tags: css, firefox, stylesheet, css-shapes

I'm using a triangle on my website as shown on http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Sadly this doesn't display correctly accross browsers when strechted a bit.

My code

```
div.triangle {
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-left: 55px solid transparent;
    border-right: 55px solid transparent;
    border-top: 15px solid #D5CDBA;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mPSj9/5/

Makes firefox produce some darker line beneath the shape. Why is that and can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a shadow, it's color, it is because of the `border-left, border-right` colors

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mPSj9/6/)

CSS

```
div.main-link-active-triangle {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-left: 55px solid transparent;
    border-right: 55px solid transparent;
    border-top: 55px solid #D5CDBA;
}
```

[**Width Background Color**](http://jsfiddle.net/mPSj9/11/)

Few Examples : [CSS triangle custom border color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450733/css-triangle-custom-border-color)

As @Aleks Dorohovich said you can use [**rgba()**](http://jsfiddle.net/mPSj9/12/) CSS3 property and making borders opaque but (Note: Won't work on <= IE8)

Comment: well yes, but I need to have the triangle flat angeled and only 15px high.

Comment: nice work, editing your answer to something totally different after the other dude posted the working solution :)

Comment: @unR Editing to a correct answer in not a bad thing, its the site which says edit the answers and correct them, I respect his answer too..I was going to state his name too there

Comment: in that case, accepted (for good formatting) - now go upvote the guy

Comment: @unR Actually thank you but you should accept his answer as that was the first which solved your issue, I just informed you the issue but he solved

Answer (score 2):

Try to change *transparent* property to *rgba* with opacity 0

For example:

```
border-left: 55px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
border-right: 55px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
```