# How to set a border color over triangle arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a custom popover. Yet i have tried this:

http://jsbin.com/uyezeq/1/edit

I am trying to achieve the same border-color over triangle arrow (you can see it at top right corner of output div) which div has. How can i do this ?

*Please do not suggest me any third party plugins like bootstrap popover or any other*

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS triangle custom border color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450733/css-triangle-custom-border-color)

Comment: I would of just used an image for the arrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a reference from [CSS triangle custom border color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450733/css-triangle-custom-border-color) i have achieved this :

http://jsbin.com/uyezeq/7/edit

Thanks to all who guid me in write direction :)