# How to make Bookmark kind of Ribbon on click of side navbar element?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have a side navigation bar in my application which consists of 4 nav items. On initial load, they should look like below -

[image]

On click of each item, the background of that item should be changed as below -

[image]

I have tried below code (with limited knowledge on CSS) and was able to get what was shown in first image. For second image It displays like this and it should done as in second image.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="col-sm-3">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Item 4</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav-pills>li {
   margin-left: -5px;
}
.nav-pills>li {
   width: 90%;
}
.nav-pills>li>a{
  color: #0D0D0D;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  padding: 15px;
}

.nav-pills>li>a:focus, .nav-pills>li>a:active{
  /*background-color: white;*/
  border:       30px solid lightgreen;
  border-left:  30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0;
  width:        100%;
```

}

[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged bootstrap-4 .. there is no longer a `nav-stacked` class?

Comment: @ZimSystem, Thanks and Removed bootstrap taggings.. I will check on nav-stacked class. I know about flex-column class to create vertical nav. What else can be used here ?

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241591/inside-transparent-arrow-on-the-left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) and [Pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box
}
body {
   width: 100wh;
   height: 100vh; 
   background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
   background-size: 400% 400%; 
   animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
   }


   @keyframes Gradient {
  0%,100% { background-position: 0% 50% }
  50% { background-position: 100% 50% } 
} 
menu{
  margin: 40px auto;
  position: relative; 
  max-width: 320px
}
menu li{
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;  
  margin-bottom: 2px
}
menu li:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:-1;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    opacity:0;
    margin-left: -30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 480px #d1e3ab;
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
menu a{
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#5e5e5e;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  text-indent: 24px;
} 
menu li:hover a{ 
  background-color: transparent; 
}
menu li:hover:before{ 
  opacity:1
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</menu>
```

Comment: I wanted to change to ribbon based on click instead of hover, so changed to hover to focus and is not working..

Comment: Why are trying to FOCUS list elements ? if you try to make a CLICK the you may consider using JAVASCRIPT click EVENT or change the structure to input & checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

- Create 2 layers using `::before` and `::after`pseudo elements having same heights equal to 50% height of the parent element.
- Apply `background`, `border-radius` and other necessary CSS properties on these layers.
- Use `skewX()` transformation on hover to create the triangular effect.

**Demo:**

```css
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  background: #333 url("https://k39.kn3.net/A01CCB6AE.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav li + li {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
}

.nav li a::before,
.nav li a::after {
  transition: transform .2s linear;
  transform-origin: left top;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  content: '';
  height: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.nav li a::after {
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}


.nav li a:hover::before {
  transform: skewX(30deg);
}

.nav li a:hover::after {
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thats great, There is a white line appearing when you hover on Item 1 and Item 4. Is there a way to fix that pls?

Comment: @ChilBud Its working fine in my chrome. In which browser (and version) you are facing this issue?

Comment: Chrome and Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @ChilBud I've Chrom Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit) and its working fine there. Please update your browser. Hopefully this issue will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting my answer using `bootstrap4` but the key point here is not relevant whether `bootstrap3` or `bootstrap4` is used. The key point here is how you can make a triangle.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/81019/

#### CSS Triangle

I am not going to explain here since it's already been explained well: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

The idea here is to use `:before` of the active `nav-link` to make a triangle with white background.

#### Calculations

[image]

If you want the tip of the triangle right in the middle of the menu, you need to calculate its total height.

```
Total height = border top (1px) + 
               padding top (1rem) +
               line height (1.5 x 1rem = 1.5rem) +
               padding bottom (1rem) +
               border bottom (1px)
```

And then you divide it by 2 for the width of the border top and bottom.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this approach and for some reason, my items are not stacked and are displayed as Item1 Item2 Item 3 and Item 4 overlapped.

Comment: As what I said in the beginning, I am using bootstrap4 and you're using bootstrap3. There are so many breaking changes between them.

Comment: Ok, Got it. Will try to fix the issue and see the output.