# How to set a border to a triangle

Tags: html, css

I've tried to set a black solid 1px border for triangle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZeCz/1925/). I write the follwoing markup:

```
<div>
</div>
```

and styles

```
div{
    position: absolute;
    left:0px; 
    top:0px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 5px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 10px solid red;
}
```

But I don't understand how to set the border for the triangle in this case.

Comment: Basically because the triangle **IS** a border...you can't add a **border** to it

Comment: But I need a triangle with the border. Did you mean that it isn't possible with CCS?

Comment: You can use the before/after pseudo element - like so http://jsfiddle.net/4ZeCz/1927/ but it looks a bit jagged..

Comment: So as @Paulie_D said , you're essentially creating a triangle using a css trick, this explains how it's made http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/full/lotjh

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS triangle custom border color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450733/css-triangle-custom-border-color)

Comment: @NickR Is it possible to remove a bottom border?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv - you can just increase the bottom border of the `before` pseudo element to `11px` rather than `10px;`

Comment: Also it seems to look a little better in Chrome - a bit smoother. Maybe it's just Firefox that's rendering it jagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this too , basically i have made a larger triangle black in colour and put it behind the red one

```
<div id="border">  
</div>

 <div id="red">
 </div>


#red{
    position: absolute;
    left:4px; 
    top:9px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 5px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 10px solid red;
    background-color:transparent;
    z-index: 99;
}

#border {
    position: absolute;
    left:0x; 
    top:0px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px; 
    border-left: 6px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 6px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 12px solid black;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

here is your solution its work

```
`div:before {
    border-bottom: 12px solid #000000;
    border-left: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    left: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    width: 0;
}

div:after {
    border-bottom: 10px solid #FF0000;
    border-left: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 111111;
}`
```