# Facebook / twitter count box css

Tags: css, facebook, border

I'm just asking how to make these boxes with css border styling ?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450733/css-triangle-custom-border-color

Comment: exactly what I needed !!!!!! Looking for hours !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is what you want.

```css
.inbox{margin:20px; cursor:pointer;}
.arrow_box {
 position: absolute;
 border: 2px solid #888;
    border-radius:5px;
    height:20px;
    width:25px;
    padding:5px 10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:-8px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#888;
}
/*  to display it on hover uncomment the below css 
  .arrow_box{display:none;} 
  .inbox:hover .arrow_box{display:inline-block;}
*/

.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
 right: 100%;
 top: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
 border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
 border-right-color: #fff;
 border-width: 8px;
 margin-top: -8px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
 border-color: rgba(136, 136, 136, 0);
 border-right-color: #888;
 border-width: 11px;
 margin-top: -11px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="inbox">Inbox
    <span class="arrow_box">25</span>
  </li>
  <li class="inbox">Spam
    <span class="arrow_box">15</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```