# Creating a triangle div with a border

Tags: html, css

I have a triangle in the top left corner of my site

```css
#corner {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="corner"></div>
```

EDIT - I want it to have a 5px red border (only on the angled side) so the triangle and the border are different colors

Ideally it will have a .png image over-top as well, but I can put another div over-top if need be

This is a corner triangle for the whole page

Comment: I made the triangle black to make it visible, and then I thought I also had to invert the color of the border. But I don't see the point if the border and the triangle have the same color. Just make it bigger.

Comment: Please explain further or show what your desired output is. Your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I apologize, the edit to the question changed what I am asking. I will clarify

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS triangle custom border color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450733/css-triangle-custom-border-color)

Comment: not that type of triangle

Comment: At some point it makes more sense to just stick an svg in there

Comment: fair enough, although the triangle I'm looking for has been answered below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way to achieve what you want is to use the **`transform`** property instead of manipulating the **`border`** and possibly even needing two elements and a lot of unnecessary code.

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sggk30np/2/) or the following snippet for a visual representation.

**Snippet:**

```css
#corner {
  /* Dimensions */
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  
  /* Positioning */
  position: absolute;
  left: -7.5em;
  top: -7.5em;
  z-index: 999;
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
  
  /* Styling */
  background-color: red;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #0c0c0c;
}
```

```html
<div id="corner"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create two divs:

```css
#corner {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 55px solid #f00;
  border-bottom: 55px solid transparent;
  border-right: 55px solid transparent;
  border-left: 55px solid #f00;
}

#corner-inner {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: -55px;
  top: -55px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="corner">
    <div id="corner-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume this is the best response, I just have to put a logo overtop as well, and I don't want to stack to many divs

Comment: Yeah, so far... I think that's as simple as it's goning to get. I couldn't work how to do this any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can even try pseudo elements `:before` and `:after`.

```css
#corner {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid #000;
}
#corner:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  border-left: 5px solid red;
  top:-50px;
  left:-50px;
  width:92px;
  height:92px;
}
#corner:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  top:-104px;
  left:-83px;
  width:93px;
  height:140px;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="corner"></div>
```

Comment: user3550879 wanted the border **only** on the alngled side.

Comment: @IShad0wk I thought it needs to cover it's all corners border:red;

Comment: *"EDIT - I want it to have a 5px red border (only on the angled side) so the triangle and the border are different colors"* - user3550879.