# Add border over triangle element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a border around a triangle. I have this so far:

#### JSFiddle

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.myDiv::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: 20px;
  border-right: 20px solid lightblue;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</div>
```

But I can't add a border to the `before` element. How can I add a border around the piece that's sticking out on the bottom ('before` element)?

(I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450733/css-triangle-custom-border-color), but I can't apply the same principle to this, since it's different shapes.)

Comment: Make a `::after` that’s 2px wider, 1px taller, and 1px to the left. Then, set the `border-color` to black.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add an **`::after`** with more **`border-width`** and different position bottom and right, its work very well. Don't forget to change **`border-color`** to **`black`** and low down the **`z-index`** by **-1**.

**Example:**

---

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.myDiv::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: 20px;
  border-right: 20px solid lightblue;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.myDiv::after {
  z-index:-1;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  bottom: -22px;
  right: 19px;
  border-right: 21px solid black;
  border-bottom: 21px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</div>
```

[**Fiddle demo**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/L20b2uwk/)

Comment: This is a pretty sneaky idea. I never thought of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `:after` element positioned behind the blue triangle.

```
.myDiv::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -22px;
  right: 19px;
  border-right: 21px solid black;
  border-bottom: 21px solid transparent;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.myDiv::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: 20px;
  border-right: 20px solid lightblue;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  z-index:10;
}

.myDiv::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -22px;
  right: 19px;
  border-right: 21px solid black;
  border-bottom: 21px solid transparent;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an SVG for the shape as well.

You create the triangle with the `polygon` tag:

```
<polygon 
class="triangle" /* CSS Styling, if you want properties instead of inline attributes */
fill="currentColor" /* To be able to change the fill with the property color in CSS */
stroke="#000" /* Match your border color */
stroke-dasharray="0, 30, 90" /* To remove the stroke from the "top" part of triangle */
points="30,4 60,4 60,30" /> /* The whole triangle figure */
```

---

**Code Snippet:**

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.myDiv svg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: -59.7px;
  color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
  <svg height="64" width="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
    <polygon class="triangle" fill="currentColor" stroke="#000" stroke-dasharray="0, 30, 90" points="30,4 60,4 60,30" />
  </svg>
</div>
```