# Displaying a centred vertical dashed line above div using CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Trying to create a vertical dashed line above each of the `progress-container` divs, that sits directly centre on top and spans the full possible height. The only way I've managed to create something similar is by adding a left border, but obviously this isn't centered.

This is a simplified demo and each input/icon represent a rendered React component so using pure CSS is my ideal scenario.

```css
.wrapperDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.progress-container {
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
}

.input-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 0.375rem 1.75rem 0.375rem 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperDiv">
  <div class="progress-container"></div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <div class="input">I have my first input here</input>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: ie. vertical dashed line like so]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "a vertical dashed line above the container"? If it's the border-top, it'll be a horizontal line. If it's border-left, it'll be a vertical line. Also, can you add the dashed border CSS to the codepen?

Comment: This is often handled through the use of an absolutely-positioned pseudo-element. That's what I'd do.

Comment: [Here's an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617217/adding-css-border-to-after-element)

Comment: that's useful. but I still run into the issue of the positioning of the vertical line.

Comment: Have updated the question to include the vertical line I'm trying to achieve..

Comment: How is the height of the vertical line above the red progress container determined?

Comment: 100% height of the div

Comment: From the top of the red box to the top of the wrapperDiv?

Comment: Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/simoncunningham/pen/mdwMgyL (line not showing, not sure :before works in codepen)

Comment: The dotted line is showing and seems OK. Not sure what the question is now!

Comment: codepen was updated to reflect new answer provided. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle this behaviour with absolutely positioned `pseudo-elements` so that you don't have to wrangle with the natural document flow of elements.

Use [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) to handling the incrementing logic programmatically.

Consider responsive container heights as well to account for varying content lengths:

```css
/* BEM naming convention used to keep selectors flat */

.progress-wrapper {
  counter-reset: step;    /* Set a counter named 'step', and its initial value is 0. */
}

.progress-step {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.progress-step::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  left: 11px;               /* relative to marker width */
  top: 5px;                 /* offset top */
  height: 100%;             /* responsive heights */
  margin: auto;
  border-left: 2px dashed black;
  z-index: -1;              /* handle stacking context */
}

.progress-step--no-step::after { /* handle the last exception, not every instance */
  display: none;          
}

.progress-step__marker {
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
}

.progress-step__marker::before {
  counter-increment: step;  /* Increment the value of section counter by 1 */
  content: counter(step);   /* Display incremented counter value */
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 22px;        /* relative to marker height */
}

.input-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 0.375rem 1.75rem 0.375rem 0.75rem;
}

.input-wrapper--large {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-wrapper">
  <div class="progress-step">
    <div class="progress-step__marker"></div>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <div class="input-wrapper__input">I have my first input here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-step">
    <div class="progress-step__marker"></div>
    <div class="input-wrapper input-wrapper--large">
      <div class="input-wrapper__input">I have my second input here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-step progress-step--no-step">
    <div class="progress-step__marker"></div>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <div class="input-wrapper__input">I have my third input here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```